# P-Value Adjustment for Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons

I am a little confused, how to utilize the p-value adjustments the correct way. And also in way over my head.

This is what I am doing so far:

1. I am running 2 Multivariate Multiple Linear Regressions with 2 sets of 13 variables as dependent variables and the same set of 4 predictors.
2. Then I go for the dependent variables trough each one and see which predictors were significant. For each DV I therefore create a Multiple Linear Regression model with all predictors and compare that to the reduced Model with only significant seeming predictors.

My question now is: Where should I correct the p-values and which should I correct for?
So 1. should I correct the p-value for the significance of the whole model OR for the significance of each predictor inside one of the models OR both?
And 2. for how many and which of the models should I correct?
Should I only correct inside the full models with all predictors OR only for the reduced models OR both?

Sorry if there are similar questions already, please point me to them if there are and they would answer this. Or other good resources, where this would be explained well.